# DPDK stop handling traffic after Rx miss on the port and not recover

Tags: dpdk

I am using DPDK 20.11.1 for environment Linux Ubuntu 20.04. I have configured DPDK based application to handle network traffic which working as expected normally.

The network traffic is at normal rate.

In certain case, DPDK application is suddenly stop handling traffic and start produce Rx missed on the NIC port. After this, DPDK application is unable to handle traffic. This issue is unrecoverable as per my troubleshoot until restart of the service is not performed.

This issue is not consistent to generate steps for replication.

Please guide how this issue can be eliminated or troubleshoot.

1. show port stats all

```
testpmd>  show port stats all

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 0  ########################
  RX-packets: 1031       RX-missed: 432        RX-bytes:  113936
  RX-errors: 0
  RX-nombuf:  0         
  TX-packets: 119        TX-errors: 0          TX-bytes:  24475

  Throughput (since last show)
  Rx-pps:            3          Rx-bps:         2952
  Tx-pps:            0          Tx-bps:          744
  ############################################################################

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 1  ########################
  RX-packets: 445        RX-missed: 0          RX-bytes:  44101
  RX-errors: 0
  RX-nombuf:  0         
  TX-packets: 175        TX-errors: 0          TX-bytes:  52725

  Throughput (since last show)
  Rx-pps:            1          Rx-bps:         1200
  Tx-pps:            0          Tx-bps:         1616
  ############################################################################

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 2  ########################
  RX-packets: 573        RX-missed: 0          RX-bytes:  152965
  RX-errors: 0
  RX-nombuf:  0         
  TX-packets: 416        TX-errors: 0          TX-bytes:  82445

  Throughput (since last show)
  Rx-pps:            1          Rx-bps:         4520
  Tx-pps:            1          Tx-bps:         2528
  ############################################################################

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 3  ########################
  RX-packets: 715        RX-missed: 0          RX-bytes:  100385
  RX-errors: 0
  RX-nombuf:  0         
  TX-packets: 393        TX-errors: 0          TX-bytes:  129439

  Throughput (since last show)
  Rx-pps:            2          Rx-bps:         2976
  Tx-pps:            1          Tx-bps:         3968
  ############################################################################
```

2. show port info all

```
********************* Infos for port 0  *********************
MAC address: XXXXXXXXXX
Device name: 0000:06:00.0
Driver name: net_e1000_igb
Firmware-version: 1.63, 0x80000ee4
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 1 Gbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 32
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 128
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv4-udp
  ipv6
  ipv6-tcp
  ipv6-udp
  user defined 15
  user defined 16
  user defined 17
Minimum size of RX buffer: 256
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 16383
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Maximum number of VMDq pools: 8
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 8
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 32
RXDs number alignment: 8
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 8
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 32
TXDs number alignment: 8
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 255

********************* Infos for port 1  *********************
MAC address: XXXXXXXXXX
Device name: 0000:06:00.1
Driver name: net_e1000_igb
Firmware-version: 1.63, 0x80000ee4
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 1 Gbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 32
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 128
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv4-udp
  ipv6
  ipv6-tcp
  ipv6-udp
  user defined 15
  user defined 16
  user defined 17
Minimum size of RX buffer: 256
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 16383
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Maximum number of VMDq pools: 8
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 8
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 32
RXDs number alignment: 8
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 8
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 32
TXDs number alignment: 8
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 255

********************* Infos for port 2  *********************
MAC address: XXXXXXXXXX
Device name: 0000:06:00.2
Driver name: net_e1000_igb
Firmware-version: 1.63, 0x80000ee4
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 1 Gbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 32
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 128
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv4-udp
  ipv6
  ipv6-tcp
  ipv6-udp
  user defined 15
  user defined 16
  user defined 17
Minimum size of RX buffer: 256
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 16383
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Maximum number of VMDq pools: 8
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 8
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 32
RXDs number alignment: 8
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 8
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 32
TXDs number alignment: 8
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 255

********************* Infos for port 3  *********************
MAC address: XXXXXXXXXX
Device name: 0000:06:00.3
Driver name: net_e1000_igb
Firmware-version: 1.63, 0x80000ee4
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 1 Gbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 32
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 128
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv4-udp
  ipv6
  ipv6-tcp
  ipv6-udp
  user defined 15
  user defined 16
  user defined 17
Minimum size of RX buffer: 256
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 16383
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Maximum number of VMDq pools: 8
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 8
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 32
RXDs number alignment: 8
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 8
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 32
TXDs number alignment: 8
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 255
```

3. show port xstats all

```
###### NIC extended statistics for port 0 
rx_good_packets: 1568
tx_good_packets: 452
rx_good_bytes: 201164
tx_good_bytes: 70034
rx_missed_errors: 432
rx_errors: 0
tx_errors: 0
rx_mbuf_allocation_errors: 0
rx_q0_packets: 0
rx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_q0_errors: 0
tx_q0_packets: 0
tx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_crc_errors: 0
rx_align_errors: 0
rx_symbol_errors: 0
rx_missed_packets: 432
tx_single_collision_packets: 0
tx_multiple_collision_packets: 0
tx_excessive_collision_packets: 0
tx_late_collisions: 0
tx_total_collisions: 0
tx_deferred_packets: 0
tx_no_carrier_sense_packets: 0
rx_carrier_ext_errors: 0
rx_length_errors: 0
rx_xon_packets: 0
tx_xon_packets: 1
rx_xoff_packets: 0
tx_xoff_packets: 433
rx_flow_control_unsupported_packets: 0
rx_size_64_packets: 1297
rx_size_65_to_127_packets: 112
rx_size_128_to_255_packets: 30
rx_size_256_to_511_packets: 57
rx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 21
rx_size_1024_to_max_packets: 51
rx_broadcast_packets: 984
rx_multicast_packets: 6
rx_undersize_errors: 0
rx_fragment_errors: 0
rx_oversize_errors: 0
rx_jabber_errors: 0
rx_management_packets: 0
rx_management_dropped: 0
tx_management_packets: 0
rx_total_packets: 2000
tx_total_packets: 886
rx_total_bytes: 231730
tx_total_bytes: 96074
tx_size_64_packets: 231
tx_size_65_to_127_packets: 143
tx_size_128_to_255_packets: 29
tx_size_256_to_511_packets: 20
tx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 11
tx_size_1023_to_max_packets: 18
tx_multicast_packets: 0
tx_broadcast_packets: 1
tx_tso_packets: 0
tx_tso_errors: 0
rx_sent_to_host_packets: 0
tx_sent_by_host_packets: 0
rx_code_violation_packets: 0
interrupt_assert_count: 1
###### NIC extended statistics for port 1 
rx_good_packets: 778
tx_good_packets: 712
rx_good_bytes: 89660
tx_good_bytes: 139953
rx_missed_errors: 0
rx_errors: 0
tx_errors: 0
rx_mbuf_allocation_errors: 0
rx_q0_packets: 0
rx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_q0_errors: 0
tx_q0_packets: 0
tx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_crc_errors: 0
rx_align_errors: 0
rx_symbol_errors: 0
rx_missed_packets: 0
tx_single_collision_packets: 0
tx_multiple_collision_packets: 0
tx_excessive_collision_packets: 0
tx_late_collisions: 0
tx_total_collisions: 0
tx_deferred_packets: 0
tx_no_carrier_sense_packets: 0
rx_carrier_ext_errors: 0
rx_length_errors: 0
rx_xon_packets: 0
tx_xon_packets: 0
rx_xoff_packets: 0
tx_xoff_packets: 0
rx_flow_control_unsupported_packets: 0
rx_size_64_packets: 554
rx_size_65_to_127_packets: 146
rx_size_128_to_255_packets: 29
rx_size_256_to_511_packets: 20
rx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 11
rx_size_1024_to_max_packets: 18
rx_broadcast_packets: 281
rx_multicast_packets: 0
rx_undersize_errors: 0
rx_fragment_errors: 0
rx_oversize_errors: 0
rx_jabber_errors: 0
rx_management_packets: 0
rx_management_dropped: 0
tx_management_packets: 0
rx_total_packets: 778
tx_total_packets: 712
rx_total_bytes: 89660
tx_total_bytes: 139953
tx_size_64_packets: 489
tx_size_65_to_127_packets: 95
tx_size_128_to_255_packets: 29
tx_size_256_to_511_packets: 27
tx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 21
tx_size_1023_to_max_packets: 51
tx_multicast_packets: 0
tx_broadcast_packets: 272
tx_tso_packets: 0
tx_tso_errors: 0
rx_sent_to_host_packets: 0
tx_sent_by_host_packets: 0
rx_code_violation_packets: 0
interrupt_assert_count: 1
###### NIC extended statistics for port 2 
rx_good_packets: 1621
tx_good_packets: 1229
rx_good_bytes: 468412
tx_good_bytes: 267609
rx_missed_errors: 0
rx_errors: 0
tx_errors: 0
rx_mbuf_allocation_errors: 0
rx_q0_packets: 0
rx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_q0_errors: 0
tx_q0_packets: 0
tx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_crc_errors: 0
rx_align_errors: 0
rx_symbol_errors: 0
rx_missed_packets: 0
tx_single_collision_packets: 0
tx_multiple_collision_packets: 0
tx_excessive_collision_packets: 0
tx_late_collisions: 0
tx_total_collisions: 0
tx_deferred_packets: 0
tx_no_carrier_sense_packets: 0
rx_carrier_ext_errors: 0
rx_length_errors: 0
rx_xon_packets: 0
tx_xon_packets: 0
rx_xoff_packets: 0
tx_xoff_packets: 0
rx_flow_control_unsupported_packets: 0
rx_size_64_packets: 405
rx_size_65_to_127_packets: 382
rx_size_128_to_255_packets: 445
rx_size_256_to_511_packets: 134
rx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 105
rx_size_1024_to_max_packets: 150
rx_broadcast_packets: 185
rx_multicast_packets: 6
rx_undersize_errors: 0
rx_fragment_errors: 0
rx_oversize_errors: 0
rx_jabber_errors: 0
rx_management_packets: 0
rx_management_dropped: 0
tx_management_packets: 0
rx_total_packets: 1621
tx_total_packets: 1229
rx_total_bytes: 468412
tx_total_bytes: 267609
tx_size_64_packets: 290
tx_size_65_to_127_packets: 483
tx_size_128_to_255_packets: 151
tx_size_256_to_511_packets: 191
tx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 53
tx_size_1023_to_max_packets: 61
tx_multicast_packets: 0
tx_broadcast_packets: 1
tx_tso_packets: 0
tx_tso_errors: 0
rx_sent_to_host_packets: 0
tx_sent_by_host_packets: 0
rx_code_violation_packets: 0
interrupt_assert_count: 1
###### NIC extended statistics for port 3 
rx_good_packets: 1528
tx_good_packets: 1441
rx_good_bytes: 285549
tx_good_bytes: 444886
rx_missed_errors: 0
rx_errors: 0
tx_errors: 0
rx_mbuf_allocation_errors: 0
rx_q0_packets: 0
rx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_q0_errors: 0
tx_q0_packets: 0
tx_q0_bytes: 0
rx_crc_errors: 0
rx_align_errors: 0
rx_symbol_errors: 0
rx_missed_packets: 0
tx_single_collision_packets: 0
tx_multiple_collision_packets: 0
tx_excessive_collision_packets: 0
tx_late_collisions: 0
tx_total_collisions: 0
tx_deferred_packets: 0
tx_no_carrier_sense_packets: 0
rx_carrier_ext_errors: 0
rx_length_errors: 0
rx_xon_packets: 0
tx_xon_packets: 0
rx_xoff_packets: 0
tx_xoff_packets: 0
rx_flow_control_unsupported_packets: 0
rx_size_64_packets: 589
rx_size_65_to_127_packets: 483
rx_size_128_to_255_packets: 151
rx_size_256_to_511_packets: 191
rx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 53
rx_size_1024_to_max_packets: 61
rx_broadcast_packets: 300
rx_multicast_packets: 0
rx_undersize_errors: 0
rx_fragment_errors: 0
rx_oversize_errors: 0
rx_jabber_errors: 0
rx_management_packets: 0
rx_management_dropped: 0
tx_management_packets: 0
rx_total_packets: 1528
tx_total_packets: 1441
rx_total_bytes: 285549
tx_total_bytes: 444886
tx_size_64_packets: 267
tx_size_65_to_127_packets: 382
tx_size_128_to_255_packets: 445
tx_size_256_to_511_packets: 92
tx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 105
tx_size_1023_to_max_packets: 150
tx_multicast_packets: 1
tx_broadcast_packets: 10
tx_tso_packets: 0
tx_tso_errors: 0
rx_sent_to_host_packets: 0
tx_sent_by_host_packets: 0
rx_code_violation_packets: 0
interrupt_assert_count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be issues with the rate of reading the traffic or processing it. Have you tried running with the example applications like `dpdk-testpmd`, and `dpdk-l2fwd`? Try running the `dpdk-testpmd` application and check the outputs of the below commands or share them here:

`show port info all`
`show port stats all`
`show port xstats all`

Comment: Please find output of dpdk-testpmd where rx-missed can be seen. This issue is not easy to reproduce